# Find the fastest running time. Solve for $n$: $100\cdot n^2 - 2^n \lt0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I've been reading a book about algorithms

> What is the smallest value of n such that an algorithm whose running time is $100n^2$ runs faster than an algorithm whose running time is $2^n$ on the same machine?

So I started solving for n and I got this far:

> $100 \cdot n^2 - 2^n \lt0$

It's been a couple of years since I've done some algebra. I'd like some help for the above equation. I've lost touch with logs too.

Comment: Try several $n$ ($5$, $10$, $12$...), actual value is small enough. (Also, $n=0$ is a solution, though I doubt that's what you want)

Comment: @Abstraction, you mean trial and error? 
How would I solve it mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can graph the equation and find where the root is and then find the value of $n$.

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20100*n%5E2-2%5En%3D0) says one root is 14.3247, so the value of $n$ is 15.

Answer (score 1):

It is not nice to solve this equation without trial and error. It can be done, using Lambert W, but that won't be nice.

Here is a process that will get us fast towards the correct answer.

- Start with $n=1$.
- Then we get $2^n=100n^2\geq100$, so $n \geq 7$.
- Then we get $2^n = 100n^2\geq4900$, so $n \geq 13$.
- Then we get $2^n\geq100n^2\geq16900$, so $n \geq 15$.
- Then we get $2^n \geq100n^2 \geq 22500$, so indeed $n=15$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by logs.  on simplifying $$100n^2<2^n$$ you get $2+2log(n)<0.301n$ so $logn<0.1505n-1$ now go for trial and error and you will get it.